# The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account. Stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I create a manage account . And I create another test account for send payment to it. I want to get payment with managed account get application fee for it. and I will send the remaining of the payment to test account .

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_...";

Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chargeParams.put("amount", 1000);
chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
chargeParams.put("source", {TOKEN});
chargeParams.put("destination", {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID});

Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

But I get this exception "The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account". I dont know where I make mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** be creating charges directly from your Android app.

The only part of the payment flow that takes place directly in a mobile app is the collection and tokenization of the customer's payment information, through the use of Stripe's [Android SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android). This is done with your publishable API key.

All other operations require the use of your *secret* API key, which should never be embedded or shared in any way with your mobile app, as it would then be easy for an attacker to retrieve it and use it to access your account.

Once you've collected the customer's payment information and created a token, you need to send this token to a backend server where you can use it to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or [a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).

In regard to the specific error you're seeing, it's happening because you set the `destination` parameter to your own account's ID. When creating charges [through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform), the `destination` parameter must be set to the ID of an account that is connected to your platform, not your own platform's account ID.